# I want to shorten my url using url rewriting, but it doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was trying to shorten the `url` more, but I was removing `.php` or `.html` file extension from the urls using url rewriting too. I can't run both at the same time.

Removing the extensions and trying to shorten link from

> site.com/profile.php?id={username}
>
> to
>
> site.com/username.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z]+)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\..*?$ $1.html [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^\..*?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Just the first thing I'm trying to do works, or removing extension(but not both, not .html and .php at the same time), or removing profile.php?id, not both.

Comment: have you working in any framework?????

Comment: @MohitKumar no, just php & html for now.

Comment: @DonPaul Do yourself a favor and start using a framework, it does all of this for you.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I can't right now, I want to solve this problem.

Comment: @DonPaul That _would_ solve this problem

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I can't move my entire project on a framework right now.

Comment: @Jonnix how can i modify it? Like (.)$ ?

Comment: @Jonnix still not working, the second rule.

Comment: @Jonnix I found out this https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34450/htaccess-two-different-rules-but-only-one-per-time but still not working.

Comment: Done. I didn't manage to solve it.

Comment: Still not working @Jonnix `RewriteRule \..*?$ $1.php [NC,L]` or `RewriteRule \..*?$ $1.html [NC] `

Comment: Is the profile bit working? (Btw, for that rule you should add an `L` to the `[]` bit.

Comment: Okay, I got confused, this isn't going to work. By the sounds of it you want `http://example.com/username` to go to `profile.php?id=username`, but at the same time you want `http://example.com/mypage` to go to `mypage.html` or `mypage.php`. Is that right? (Have removed some previous comments to not confuse others.)

Comment: @Jonnix yes. This is right!

Comment: @DonPaul Then consider this, how would httpd know that `mypage` wasn't a username? The solution is to add an extra part to the URL e.g. have `/profile/username` rewrite to `profile.php?id=username` or similar. Something that makes it different from every other page.

Comment: Yes, this works. But I want a direct link, without profile. site.com/username, without /profile/ or /p/ or anything.

Comment: Okay, so another question. Are you fine with saying, if there is a file called `username.php` that /username would go to `username.php`, not to `profile.php`?

Comment: Yes, I have a constraint that the usernames contain only letters and numbers.

Comment: Can you read my comment again and think it through. You have a URL `/mypage` it has only letters or numbers (ignoring /), so is it a file to process, or is it a username? What is that decision based on?

Answer (score 0):

Wy has it to be with Rewrite? You can do

```
 function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
 document.title = response.pageTitle;
 window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath); }
```

like its in here: [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page/3354511#3354511)

**EDIT**

I guess you can try this [HERE](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/)

Comment: yes, but I want that link to be accessible from anywhere, not only from my website.

Comment: http://www.Something.com/?userID=2&profile....... normal url,  you want to do this http://www.Something.com/id2  ? (just examples) without a framework like codeigniter, laravel or something else i dont know if its possible. I mean its possible but you will have a lot of work to do. Or you either change to a framework or you better change the url on page without reloading it

Comment: Yes, I want to transform site.com/username and to remove .php extension like site.com/login.php to site.com/login .

Comment: No, I guess is not what I need.

Comment: you can do ````site.com/login.php to site.com/login```` with that link that i just gave you